# htmlpurifier removes all the formatting done by CKEDitor

Tags: php, security, ckeditor, xss, htmlpurifier

I am using CKEditor to let the user post their comments. I thought to use the htmlpurifier to secure my html. But when I tried it, it actually removes all the formatting done by CKEditor. 
The CKEditor generated the following html

```
<div class="originalpost"><span style="color:#B22222;">
<em><u><strong><span style="font-size:250%;">
This is Pakistan</span></strong></u></em></span></div>
```

After purifying with htmlpurifier the html became like this

```
<div class="&quot;originalpost&quot;"><span><em><u><strong>
<span>This is Pakistan</span></strong></u></em></span></div>
```

It actually removes all the inline css styles and also `class="&quot;originalpost&quot;"` is not understand able.
I have used the following way to purify the html with htmlpurifier

```
require_once("path\HTMLPurifier.auto.php");
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
$html = "xyzhtml";
$clean_html = $purifier->purify($html);
```

I want to keep the user formatting, How can I configure htmlpurifier to keep the user formatting also don't change the inline css.

Comment: There are a number of XSS attacks involving the `style` attribute, are you sure that you want to enable it? One of the purposes of HTMLPurifier is to get rid of them.

Comment: @DiegoAgulló, How can I keep the user formatting without allowing style attribute, as I am using CKEditor for posting comments.

Answer (score 2):

> It actually removes all the inline css styles

Inline styles are indeed dangerous - JavaScript can be injected into them using `url()`, IE's dodgy `expression()`  and browser-specific behavioural extensions.

HTMLPurifier *can* parse inline styles and filter the dangerous properties and values. You can turn this on by including `style` in your whitelisted attributes.

```
$config->set('HTML.AllowedAttributes', '*.style, ...');
```

`style` is not included in the default attribute list because parsing styles is a lot of extra complexity (with accompanying chance of bugs) and most applications don't need it.

You can configure the properties that are permitted using `%CSS.AllowedProperties` if you wish.

I can't reproduce the `&quot;` problem but certainly ensuring PHP's `magic_quotes_gpc` option is turned off is an all-round good thing...

Answer (score 0):

I bet that you need to turn off Sybase quotes.